# hydrodynamic entrance length [developing flow]. Non-native speaker needs some help

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, flow

I am currently writing my thesis in English as an non-native speaker. From time to time, I struggle quite a bit with the correct expression of the sentences. Could you have a look on the highlighted sentence below? I am quite unsatisfied with the expression. What do you think? Do you understand the sentence?

Thank you for any help!

---

> In this expression, K and fd are the incremental pressure drop number
>   and Fanning friction factor for fully developed flow. C is a constant
>   dependent on the geometry of the duct cross-section, while the
>   dimensionless entrance length z+ is defined by:
>
> EQUATION
>
> with z_h as the hydrodynamic entrance length, given by:
>
> EQUATION
>
> **Since the hydrodynamic entrance length either exceeded, or almost
>   reached the total channel length L over the entire range of
>   Reynold numbers considered for the validation, a fixed value of z_h=L
>   was applied here.**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about physics.

Comment: Yeah, but, in all fairness, the excerpt looks good to me (I can't judge the term "hydrodynamic entrance length" though, if that's what the author wants).

Comment: I think your English is not bad. I think the sentence is fairly clear, although I don't understand the content.